# Load CSV with blank values in MonetDB

Tags: database, csv, monetdb

I am trying to load a CSV file where values that should be NULL are simply blank. For example, consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    float a,
    float b,
    float c
);
```

I am trying to load a file that looks like this (some rows may have no NULL values, others may have several).

```
1.0,1.2,1.3
1.4,,1.5
1.6,,,
1.9,2.0,1.2
```

I would like the empty fields (e.g., 2nd field in the second row) to be NULL in the database.

I am using the following command to load the csv file:

```
 COPY INTO table from '/path/to/file.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',','\n','"' NULL AS '';
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to import table line 2 field b 'double' expected in ''
```

Should I be passing anything else to the load command (other than NULL AS '')?

Answer (score 0):

No, you seem to be doing this correctly. I have tried to replicate your test and it works for me. Your error only seems to occur if you leave out the NULL AS '' part of your answer.

There are several minor errors in the code you provided, the correct code would be:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    a float,
    b float,
    c float
);

COPY INTO test from '/path/to/file.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',','\n','"' NULL AS '';
```

And in your file you should remove the extra ',' character:

```
1.0,1.2,1.3
1.4,,1.5
1.6,,
1.9,2.0,1.2
```

If this fails, try updating your version of MonetDB.